# How does 'to obtain' develop to mean 'to prevail'?

Tags: etymology

What's an intuitive derivation behind definition 2 of [**obtain**](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/obtain), that helps to internalise its meaning:

> 2. [no object] [formal] Be prevalent, customary, or established
>
> [ODO]

How does the etymology (listed in that link and [here](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=obtain&searchmode=none)) lead to the foregoing meaning?

I haven't pasted the Etymonline entry from above, because it refers only to the more common definition 1 [ie: to  get, acquire (something)], about which I'm NOT asking here.

Comment: It just has 2, separate meanings...

Comment: It's not that much of a stretch to consider something that's prevalent, customary, and established to have _taken a hold_ and be now _holding fast_ (to its position, or just in general). The two meanings don't seem that far apart or incompatible to me.

Comment: (ODO sense 2) 'obtain' has been bleached (for part of its range of application) so thoroughly as to be replaceable by 'subsist' or even 'be'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The OED has examples of the intransitive *obtain* dating from as early as 1441, but gives no specific etymology for this use.

However if you look at the general etymology, which indicates *obtain* coming to English via Norman-French it is instructive. Particularly look at the the classical Latin. Included in the English meanings of *obtinēre* are words such as *win, prevail, hold, possess, to be prevalent, customary or established*.

> Etymology:  < Anglo-Norman obtenir, optenir, optiner and Middle
>   French, French obtenir (strong stem obtegn- , obteign- ) to gain, to
>   achieve (1283 in Old French as optenir ), to be victorious (c1380), to
>   win (15th cent.), to succeed in attaining (c1500), to subsist (c1508),
>   to hold, occupy (a1525) < classical Latin obtinēre to gain, to
>   achieve, secure, to win, to be victorious, to prevail, succeed, to
>   hold, possess, occupy, to be prevalent, customary, or established, in
>   post-classical Latin also to conquer (from 8th cent. in British
>   sources), to arrive at a place (11th cent. or earlier) < ob- ob-
>   prefix + tenēre to hold, keep (see tenant n.).

Comment: A far better answer than United seem able to come up with.